# is it possible for the same unchanged code to sometimes run and sometimes not?

Tags: c++, exception, opengl, error-handling

I have recently been learning OpenGL and whilst I have been using it, I have come across a situation where my code does not run and I tried some things that didn't work, then one day, without making any changes, the code just ran.

At first I thought that I must have accidentally changed something or forgotten about a change I'd made, even though I was pretty sure I hadn't but this has happened to me about 3 or 4 times now the most recent being my current situation.

I have a long OpenGL program which is a first person shooter and I wanted to add a function that allows the user to alter the sensitivity by holding the up or down key as the game is running. Therefore, I added this code to the main file:

```
void change_sensitivity(GLFWwindow* window);
float sensitivity = 0.3f; //make sensitivity a global variable

... //all the main code//

void mouse_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos)   
{
...
// I remove this line:
// float sensitivity = 0.3f;
// as it is now global
...
}

void change_sensitivity(GLFWwindow* window)
{
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_UP) == GLFW_PRESS)
        sensitivity += 0.01;
    else if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_DOWN) == GLFW_PRESS)
        sensitivity -= 0.01;
}
```

After adding this to code that previously ran correctly, I get an exception thrown by this line:

```
GLCall(glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(a_shader_ID, model.c_str()), 1, GL_FALSE, &a_model_matrix[0][0]));
```

I then commented out all the code that I added so that the code was the same as before and I still get the exception thrown.

I think it is understandable that this line has nothing to do with the code that I just added and it makes no sense that the added code would have caused this issue. This is actually the second time that this line of code has been throwing an exception after a change of code. Last time fixed it by not making any changes to the code and eventually it ran which I'm hoping will happen again but I would like to know what could be the cause of this very random behaviour?

Comment: This is called non-determinism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is it possible for the same unchanged code to sometimes run and sometimes not?

Yes. If that's what you observed, then you should already be aware that it is possible.

For example, if the program has undefined behaviour. When beahaviour is undefined, "anyhthing" is possible for any reason whether something unrelated is changed or not.

Another example are concurrent programs, which can behave differently depending on how the task scheduler allocates time.

Lastly, differences in run-time input can obviously change the behaviour of "unchanged" code.

Comment: Ok thanks so, I have two questions. 1. What is a program with undefined behaviour? 2. Can you make a program work by always having the same tasks running?

Comment: @cooldud There are many ways to write bugs whose behaviour is undefined in C++. For example, reading an indeterminate value: `int i; int j = i;`. 2. I don't understand your question.

Comment: @cooldud: "*Can you make a program work by always having the same tasks running?*" You could also make it work by fixing the problems in your program that cause it to invoke UB, not work well with threading, or otherwise exhibit non-deterministic behavior.

Comment: @ eerorika Ok thanks, ill have to read up on undefined behaviour and see if I can find what is wrong with my code

Comment: @Nicol Bolas, I dont know what could be causing undefined behaviour, I also dont see why the example given by eerorkia doesnt work because int i will give i a random value, then j is just assigned that same random value

Comment: @cooldud: Think about it this way: `int i; int j = i; if( i > 1234 ){ something(); } else { different(); }`. Depending on what the compiler decides to make from it, and whatever value i assumes when running the program will do something or different on each run. Here's what you should do: Enable all warnings and treat them as errors; if using GCC or clang options are `-Wall -Werror -pedantic`